# typescript generic method type annotation

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

In the following method I have the problem that I can't find a type for the changes parameter without getting an error. This is a normal nestjs service that is generic and should cover the standard crud functions. But in the update function i dont find a generic type for the changes.

It would be logical for me if I can use the type Model T, unfortunately the mongoose does not allow.

Open to ideas, thank you in advance.

```
  async updateOne(
    conditions: Partial<Record<keyof T, unknown>>,
    changes: any, // type for cahnges
    // projection: string | Record<string, unknown> = {},
    // options: Record<string, unknown> = {},
  ): Promise<T> {
    try {
      return await this.model.findOneAndUpdate(
        conditions as FilterQuery<T>,
        changes,
      );
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('generic service error:  ' + err);
      throw new InternalServerErrorException();
    }
  }
```

Here the complete CRUD Service class

```
import { Injectable, InternalServerErrorException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Document, FilterQuery, Model } from 'mongoose';

@Injectable()
export abstract class GenericCrudService<T extends Document> {
  constructor(private readonly model: Model<T>) {}

  async findAll(
    conditions: Partial<Record<keyof T, unknown>>,
    projection: string | Record<string, unknown> = {},
    options: Record<string, unknown> = {},
  ): Promise<T[]> {
    try {
      return await this.model.find(
        conditions as FilterQuery<T>,
        projection,
        options,
      );
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('generic error:  ' + err);
      throw new InternalServerErrorException();
    }
  }

  async updateOne(
    conditions: Partial<Record<keyof T, unknown>>,
    changes: any,
    // projection: string | Record<string, unknown> = {},
    // options: Record<string, unknown> = {},
  ): Promise<T> {
    try {
      return await this.model.findOneAndUpdate(
        conditions as FilterQuery<T>,
        changes,
      );
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('generic service error:  ' + err);
      throw new InternalServerErrorException();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mongoose's `updateOne` typedef:

```
 updateOne(update?: UpdateQuery<this> | UpdateWithAggregationPipeline, options?: QueryOptions | null, callback?: Callback): Query<any, this>;
```

They reference a type [`UpdateQuery<T>`](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/7175e0294455ed5df387538c2ac4d94b56871718/index.d.ts#L2660). Is that what are you're looking for?

Comment: perfekt that works :) On the create method i use the reference type ( string | Record<string, unknown>) but it dont work.

````  
async createG(
    object: string | Record<string, unknown>,
  ): Promise<T> {
    try {
      return await this.model.create(object);
    } catch (err) {
      throw new InternalServerErrorException();
    }
  }
````

Comment: if it works then you can flag my answer as accepted one